# Postgres stored procedure returning same epoch for multiple calls to now()

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, execution-time

I wrote a code to get the execution time of procedure call using below stored procedure. But the problem is the output is showing `start_time` and `end_time` having same epoch value and hence the execution_time is always returned as 0. Could you please help me why I am getting same epoch value for both the calls to now() ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.calculate_execution_time()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
    DECLARE
        start_time float;
        end_time float;
    BEGIN
        SELECT extract(epoch from now()) into start_time;
        call public.another_stored_procedure();
        SELECT extract(epoch from now()) into end_time;
        raise notice 'Execution time = % - % = % seconds', end_time, start_time, (end_time - start_time);
    END;
$procedure$
;
```

Sample output of:
`call public.calculate_execution_time()`

```
Execution time = 1620213218.485702 - 1620213218.485702 = 0 seconds
```

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) "*Since these functions return the start time of the current transaction, their values do not change during the transaction*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having `now()` return a constant time -- when the transaction started -- is considered a feature rather than a bug.  It is actually handy for long-running stored procedure.

You want [`clock_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) instead:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT extract(epoch from clock_timestamp) into start_time;
    call public.another_stored_procedure;
    SELECT extract(epoch from clock_timestamp) into end_time;
    raise notice 'Execution time = % - % = % seconds', end_time, start_time, (end_time - start_time);
END;
```

Comment: More precisely: `now()` returns the start of the _transaction_ which is not necessarily the same as the invocation time of the procedure

Comment: Great thanks @GordonLinoff that works. I think returning a constant time for now() is for some kind of transactional consistency of calling `now` function across a long running storedproc (transaction) ?